# Share object between components

Tags: object, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to split a [Vue view I've created](https://github.com/taconaut/Sppd.TeamTuner/blob/master/Frontend/src/views/user/Cards.vue) into two components (filter and list). I've tried to apply the principals described in the blog post [Sharing Data Between Components in Vue.js](https://dev.to/alexmourer/sharing-data-between-components-invuejs-48me) and adapted the code to notify an object instead of string.

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/component-data-sharing-example-7bi4i?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) has files:

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <UsrMsg @inputData="updateMessage"/>
    <Results :messages="childData"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import UsrMsg from "./components/UsrMsg";
import Results from "./components/Results";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    UsrMsg,
    Results
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      childData: {}
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateMessage(variable) {
      console.log("2) App", variable);
      this.childData = variable;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

userMsg.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <input placeholder="Enter Text Here" v-model="messages.first" @keyup.enter="submit">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "UsrMsg",
  data: function() {
    return {
      messages: {
        first: null,
        second: null
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    submit: function() {
      console.log("1) UsrMsg", this.messages);
      this.$emit("inputData", this.messages);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Results.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <li v-for="(message, index) in messageList" :item="message" :key="index">{{ message }}</li>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Results",
  props: {
    messages: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      messageList: []
    };
  },
  watch: {
    messages: function() {
      console.log("3) Results", this.messages);
      this.messageList.push(this.messages.first);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

When entering a value into the text box and hitting entrer the first time it works. Following is being logged to console:

```
1) UsrMsg Object {first: "csqwa", second: null}
2) App Object {first: "csqwa", second: null}
3) Results Object {first: "csqwa", second: null}
```

When entering a second value and hitting enter, `Results.vue` does NOT receive a notification. Following is being logged to console:

```
1) UsrMsg Object {first: "csqwa6", second: null}
2) App Object {first: "csqwa6", second: null}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code in your UsrMsg.vue in to this:

```
this.$emit("inputData", {...this.messages});
```

or in yur Results.vue

```
 methods: {
    updateMessage(variable) {
      console.log("2) App", variable);
      this.childData = {...variable};
    }
  }
```

The reason for the behavior is the change detection system. You send same object reference over and over again. So change detection system can't understand whether object is changed or not.
Corrected [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/component-data-sharing-example-oer33)

Comment: Cheers, this works. Could you give me a keyword to google as to what ... does? (I'm pretty new to  web development and couldn't figure out yet, what it does).

Comment: @Philippe Well it's not just a keyword. References is a concept shared by most programming languages (Like pointers in C). In frameworks like Vue, Angular etc. there exists a change detector mechanism to detect changes when you bind objects into views. And this binding made on the level you define in the view. So in your view if you bind and object to something. It will watch for the changes  to the object reference not for the properties of the object.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the props are updated in the parent component does not mean the updated data will be passed down again. Put a key on Results `:key="reloadKey"`
Then inside `updateMessage` just add `this.reloadKey++` (of course add this to the data property on the parent.)